# Multiple concurrent fsm Fysom

Tags: python, linux, fsm

I was writing a code in python to do some operations , these operations has to be concurrent the reason why I draw my FSM to be as two concurrent FSMs. while using Fysom in python i thought of having a definition of two FSMs. But at some point i was thinking how would the transition happen; i get confused a little bit here and that's why I am asking your support. If any one can please help , I would be grateful .. This is the way i defined the fsms please tell me if this makes no sense in Fysom or no

```
fsm1 = fysom({
'initial':'Idle',
'events':[
    {'name':'sc','src':'Idle','dst':'percent30'},
    {'name':'sc','src':'percent30','dst':'percent60'},
    {'name':'sc','src':'percent60','dst':'percent90'},
    {'name':'sc','src':'percent90','dst':'Idle'}
    ],
'callbacks':{
    'onIdle':onIdle,
    'onRead':onpercent30,
    'onTurnon':onpercent60,
    'onDisplay':onpercent90
    }
    })  

      fsm2 = fysom({
    'initial':'SR',
    'events':[
        {'name':'Right','src':'SR','dst':'SL'},
        {'name':'Left','src':'SL','dst':'SR'}
        ],
    'callbacks':{
        'onIdle':onSR,
        'onRead':onSL
        }
})
```

The transition which will take me out of fsm1 to fsm2 is not added, this is the part where i get confused and i wanted to ask if what i was thinking of is maybe completely not possible and i have to merge both in one.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use threading

```
            from fysom import Fysom
            import threading
            from termcolor import colored
            import time


            def onIdle(e):
                print 'Fan is off'
            def ons30(e):
                print 'Fan is running at 30% speed'
            def ons60(e):
                print 'Fan is running at 60% speed'
            def ons90(e):
                print 'Fan is running at 90% speed'
            def onSwingingRight(e):
                if fsm1.current != "Idle":
                    print 'Fan is swinging right'
            def onSwingingLeft(e):
                if fsm1.current != "Idle":
                    print 'Fan is swinging left'
            def onnoswinging(e):
                if fsm1.current != "Idle":
                    print 'Fan is not swinging'
            def onswinging(e):
                if fsm1.current != "Idle":
                    print 'Fan is swinging'
            def onMeasure(e):
                    print colored('                                 Measuring Temperature', 'red')
            def onMedian(e):
                    print colored('                                 Finding the Median', 'red')
            def onLCD(e):
                    print colored('                                 Updating the LCD', 'red')


            fsm1 = Fysom(
                {'initial': 'Idle','events':
                    [
                        {'name': 'sc', 'src': 'Idle', 'dst': 's30'},
                        {'name': 'sc', 'src': 's30', 'dst': 's60'},
                        {'name': 'sc', 'src': 's60', 'dst': 's90'},
                        {'name': 'sc', 'src': 's90', 'dst': 'Idle'}
                    ],
                 'callbacks': {
                             'onIdle': onIdle,
                             'ons30': ons30,
                             'ons60': ons60,
                             'ons90': ons90}
                })

            fsm2 = Fysom(
                {'initial': 'SwingingRight','events':
                    [
                        {'name': 'right', 'src': 'SwingingRight', 'dst': 'SwingingLeft'},
                        {'name': 'left', 'src': 'SwingingLeft', 'dst': 'SwingingRight'}
                    ],
                  'callbacks': {
                             'onSwingingRight': onSwingingRight,
                             'onSwingingLeft': onSwingingLeft
                             }
                })

            fsm3 = Fysom(
                {'initial': 'noswinging','events':
                    [
                        {'name': 'swing', 'src': 'noswinging', 'dst': 'swinging'},
                        {'name': 'swing', 'src': 'swinging', 'dst': 'noswinging'}
                    ],
                  'callbacks': {
                             'onnoswinging': onnoswinging,
                             'onswinging': onswinging
                             }
                })

            fsm4 = Fysom(
                {'initial': 'Measure','events':
                    [
                        {'name': 'timeup', 'src': 'Measure', 'dst': 'Median'},
                        {'name': 'l', 'src': 'Median', 'dst': 'LCD'},
                        {'name': 'l', 'src': 'LCD', 'dst': 'Measure'}
                    ],
                  'callbacks': {
                             'onMeasure': onMeasure,
                             'onMedian': onMedian,
                             'onLCD':onLCD
                             }
                })

            def controlThreadLoop():
                while True:
                    input = raw_input(">>>>>  \n")
                    if input == 'sc':
                        fsm1.sc()
                    elif input == 'swing':
                        fsm3.swing()
                    elif input == 'left':
                        fsm2.left()
                    elif input =='right':
                        fsm2.right()

            def monitoringThreadLoop():
                while True:
                    time.sleep(5.0)
                    fsm4.timeup()
                    fsm4.l()
                    fsm4.l()


            controlThread = threading.Thread(target=controlThreadLoop)
            monitoringThread = threading.Thread(target=monitoringThreadLoop)
            controlThread.start();
            monitoringThread.start();
```